# Не работает UPDATE записи в БД MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Есть окно редактирования анкетных данных пользователя, в нем есть кнопка, по нажатию на которою должны обновляться данные пользователя в БД MySQL

Есть отдельный кусок кода для идентификации пользователя, ID которого заносится в PHP-сессию:

```
$_SESSION['user_ID']
```

А это кусок кода для определения нажатия кнопки и последующего обновления записи в БД:

```
if(!empty($_POST['update']))
{
$update=mysql_query("
                    UPDATE Users u SET u.Type=6 WHERE u.user_ID=".$_SESSION['user_ID']."
                    ");
}
```

Собственно этот-то кусок кода и не работает, вернее не передается значение, хранящееся в сессии, поскольку проверка прямого объявления переменной в цикле запись обновляет прекрасно, например вот так:

```
if(!empty($_POST['update']))
{
$user_ID=12345;
$update=mysql_query("
                    UPDATE Users u SET u.Type=6 WHERE u.user_ID=$user_ID
                    ");
}
```

Сначала я думал, что проблема в кавычках, т.е. в типе данных переменной $user_ID, но следующая проверка показала "Integer":

```
echo $get=gettype($user_ID);
```

После я начал использовать PHP-сессию и var_dump() говорит, что ID пользователя туда передается, но вот обновление самой записи по нажатию кнопки не происходит?!

Уж и не знаю, что еще предположить..

Заранее спасибо за ваши комментарии!

Answer (score 0):

1. попробуйте для начала использовать проверку if( isset($_POST['update']) )
2. обрабатывайте переменные перед запросом в базу данных, формируйте сначала запрос в отдельной переменной и потом отправляйте в mysql_query
3. в запросе самом (в базу данных) если не ошибаюсь ошибка с "Users u", возможно вы забыли присваивание через "as" -> "Users as u" ?

Comment: Dr. Mc My, последовал Вашему совету из пункта 1, но, к сожалению, нужного результата это не дало

P.S. Пункт 2 я уже пробовал - на мой взгляд, это более длинная форма кода, а результат тот же.

А вот с пунктом 3 я не согласен - при обозначении аббревиатур, как в MySQL, так и в Oracle, можно опускать "as", на синтаксис это никак не влияет - проверено..)

Comment: на счет второго пункта, результат может быть и тот же, а вот sql-инъекции явно вас огорчат потом.

Comment: Вы про тот случай, когда можно в текстовое поле вставить кусок своего кода и он отправится через форму на сервер? На текущем этапе я не собираюсь давать пользователям такой "великолепной" возможности - будут отправлять только то, что можно "выбрать из списка".. у меня еще есть голова на плечах!)

P.S. Кстати, я нашел решение для своей задачи - нужно зашивать ID пользователя в саму форму, а не в сессию, видимо это единственный вариант..

Answer (score 0):

Нужно зашивать ID пользователя в саму форму, а не в сессию! (dk)